# swagger doesn't show individual endpoints within a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger

I am using Swagger for the first time and I can't get the details of individual endpoints to show up in the json response within a resource.

Simplified, I have:

```
# api.rb
require 'grape-swagger'
module API
  class Base < Grape::API
  version 'v1', using: :path
  format :json

  resource :items do
    desc 'Operations about items'
    get '/:id' do
      desc 'retrieve data for a single item'
      # do something here
    end
  end
end
```

In the output, I would expect to see something like:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "0.1",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "produces": 
  [
    "name": "application/json",
  ],
  "resources": 
  [ 
    {          
       "name": "items",
       "description": "Operations about items",
       "apis": [
         {
           "path": "/items/:id.{format}",
           "description": "retrieve data for a  single item"
         }
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead I get:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "0.1",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "produces": 
  [
     "application/json"
  ],
  "apis": 
  [
    {
      "path": "/items.{format}",
      "description": "Operations about items"
    }
  ]
}
```

what am I doing wrong? (using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1)

Answer (score 1):

You have to mount the resource first

```
mount Items
```

Comment: thanks. Where does that need to be placed in the sample code? I am getting an unitialized constant error for Items

Comment: `Items` is assumed to be class, it goes before the `resource` method. And typically each resource is split out into it's own file and inherits from `Base` much like rails controllers.